# Why do I have to cast Excel.Cells but not Excel.End?

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop

I got the following snippet from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168292%28v=office.11%29.aspx#excelobj_link9). I was curious about: Why do I have to Cast the `rng.Cells Object` into `Excel.Range` and why do I do not have to cast the `rng.End Object` into `Excel.Range`. Since leaving the `Directcast` gives me the error that while Option Strict On implicit conversion from Object to Excel.Range is not allowed. So I checked MSDNs [Range.End Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.end%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and it says that the return type is a Range object, ok that is why I dont have to cast that type into `Excel.Range`. But looking at the [Range.Cells Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.cells%28v=office.15%29.aspx) I am confused since it says that `Range.Cells` returns an `Excel.Range object` as well. So could anyone expain to me why I have to cast the `Range.Cells` but not the `Range.End` returntype?

```
Private Function GetDocPropRange() As Excel.Range
Dim rng As Excel.Range = _
  ThisApplication.Range("DocumentProperties")

Dim rngStart As Excel.Range = _
  DirectCast(rng.Cells(1, 1), Excel.Range)
Dim rngEnd As Excel.Range = _
  rng.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(0, 1)

Return ThisApplication.Range(rngStart, rngEnd) 
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast to `Range` because the return type of the *overload* `Cells(Object, Object)` is `Object`.

Picture it as this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Cells() As Excel.Range

Public ReadOnly Property Cells(rowIndex As Object, columnIndex As Object) As Object
```

[image: Visual studio]

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Could you maybe tell me where I can find the information on msdn. Just that I can help myself with further similar issues. Thanks a lot!

Comment: IMO the docs are not that good. However, the intellisense in VS should provide you with the required information. See my edit.

Comment: Great Thanks! Now I am prepared